# android facebook integration not getting userinformation

Tags: android, facebook

In my android app i am giving facebook permission as below

> "email", "publish_stream","user_location",
>   "user_birthday","read_stream",
>               "user_education_history","user_hometown","user_work_history"

It is working fine and returning all the corresponding field in my test account. But when i am trying that in another account it only gives the **email** and **basic string** .Why this happen, is it because of privacy setting ?? When i try [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2F&version=v2.1) of both account i am getting value .Any one faced this before

Comment: publish_stream is deprecated since years (it is publish_actions only now). where do you guys copy your code from?
also, read_stream will only get approved for apps without a native facebook experience (TVs, for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use these extended permissions with other users than admins/testers/developers of the app, then you have to pass your app to Review at facebook. The process is outlined here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review