# Can't grant publish permission by Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK for Android, but sometimes the code below fails to grant permission:

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

The problem depends on the using Facebook account, some account can work normally but others can't, and the only rule I know is that accounts with problems are all non-primitive accounts, which means is used only for games or app tests.

Is there any permission limitations for such accounts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to a similar question: [android facebook integration not getting userinformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761814/android-facebook-integration-not-getting-userinformation/25761913#25761913)

I guess you're testing it with app admins/testers/developers, and with other users. As long as your app didn't pass the Facebook review process, those other users will not be able to grant permission other than the basic ones.